# Best way to refactor this in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

```
private final ExecutorService executorParsers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

public void parse(List<MyObjInt> objs) {
   //... bunch of elided stuff ....

   CompletionService<AsupParseObj> parserService = new ExecutorCompletionService<AsupParseObj>(executorParsers);

   for (final AsupStoreObj obj : objs) {
      parserService.submit(new ParseThread(obj));
   }
}
```

I would like to DI the "ParseThread" but surely there has to be a better way to do this than burying a call to getBean on a prototype scoped bean and as I am new to Spring I figured I would ask...

Comment: With Spring DI, you need to make your object more like a POJO. So given that, there is are a few ways I can sort of envision where you can go with your code. Can you provide a larger snippet and some additional context for what you are trying to do?

Comment: looks like your ParseThread does not have any other dependency other than the AsupStoreObject ... in this case ... what do you want spring to help?

Comment: Well my intention was to be able to inject the ParseThread callables so that I can more easily switch out / mock those instead of being tied as this code is to a specific implementation of ParseThread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the full configuration using `lookup-method` (see [*3.4.6.1 Lookup method injection*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection)):

```
<bean id="executorParsers" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
        factory-method="newFixedThreadPool" 
        destroy-method="shutdownNow">
    <constructor-arg value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="parserService" class="java.util.concurrent.CompletionService">
    <constructor-arg ref="executorParsers"/>
</bean>

<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
    <lookup-method name="createThread" bean="parseThread"/>
</bean>

<bean id="parseThread" class="ParseThread" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true"/>
```

And the Java code:

```
abstract class Foo {

    @Autowired
    CompletionService parserService;

    protected abstract ParseThread createThread();

    public void parse(List<MyObjInt> objs) {
        for (final AsupStoreObj obj : objs) {
            ParseThread t = createThread();
            t.setObject(obj);
            parserService.submit(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you cannot pass any parameters to `lookup-method` (see [SPR-7431](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-7431) and my article [Creating prototype Spring beans on demand using lookup-method](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html)), hence the need for artificial `setObject()`.

If you don't like `abstract` methods/classes, lookup method can be non-abstract no-op method or (better) the default implementation can throw an exception. Spring will override the implementation at runtime, effectively calling `getBean()` for you.

Bonus: I translated `Executor`/`CompletionService` to Spring managed beans as well. Note that Spring supports these out-of-the-box: [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Comment: For the Spring version 3.0.5 I had to change java.util.concurrent.CompletionService to java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService because CompletionService is an interface, so the instantiation could not succeed due to the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what you think Spring is going to buy you here, but I would inject a factory of some sort that spits out `Runnable`/`Callable`'s.

```
private final ExecutorService executorParsers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

@Autowired
private CallableFactory myCallableFactory = new MyCallableFactory(); //create this factory

public void parse(List<MyObjInt> objs) {
   //... bunch of elided stuff ....

   CompletionService<AsupParseObj> parserService = new ExecutorCompletionService<AsupParseObj>(executorParsers);

   for (final AsupStoreObj obj : objs) {
      parserService.submit(myCallableFactory.createCallable(obj));
   }
}
```

You could also inject the `ExecutorService` with Spring too.