# Configuring a prototype bean with singleton members / value arguments

Tags: java, xml, spring

A common pattern I am falling into with my beans is as follows:

```
public class PrototypeBean {
    private SingletonBean singletonBean;
    private int value;
    public PrototypeBean(int value, singletonBean) {
        this.value = value;
        this.singletonBean = singletonBean;
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is the cleanest way to instantiate a prototype bean like this if I do not know what value will be until runtime.  My current pattern is as follows:

```
public class FactoryImpl implements Factory{
    private SingletonBean singletonBean;

    public FactoryImpl(SingletonBean singletonBean) {
       this.singletonBean = singletonBean;
    }

    public PrototypeBean getPrototypeBean(int value) {
       return new PrototypeBean(value, singletonBean);
    }
}
```

Where Factoryimpl is wired together in XML.  This still seems horrible to me and feels like I am breaking IoC.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this in spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most wanted features missing in Spring I came across. Basically your solution is the best workaround I can think of (just make `singletonBean` and `value` fields `final`).

Another approach would be to let Spring create `PrototypeBean` with only one constructor argument (`SingletonBean`) and passing `value` afterwards (see: [Best way to refactor this in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416655/best-way-to-refactor-this-in-spring/8416805#8416805)). However this is less clean as it allows one to create half-initialized object.

The best solution would be to take advantage of parametrized `<lookup-method/>` - feature that waits to be implemented in Spring: [SPR-7431](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7431). Don't forget to vote and comment!